# PayPal Django

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using Django-PayPal plugin (http://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal/tree/master), which works almost fine with one problem.

I followed integration process and think that everything is the same as in the guide.
But there is the problem, that I always get the INVALID response flag. I will not be able to determine the sucessfull IPN.

Do you know, how to not get the INVALID response in the IPN?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but some might still benefit from this.

You have to have "Payment Review" disabled for the PayPal test account you use to make the payment with. Then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing a site using this at the moment, and when using the sandbox I get the correct responses for the payment status, however the buyers email is always marked as invalid.

I believe it's due to the sandbox environment.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting an INVALID response from IPN for such a long time....only to figure out that I was using the live server (www.paypal.com) instead of the sandbox (sandbox.paypal.com).